# Using Lambda function and to continue despite Key Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, conditional-statements

I am looking to continue to use a for-loop or lambda function despite throwing a `KeyError`

```
df_dates = ['7/1/2021', '8/1/2021', '8/2/2021']
```

`df_values` :

```
    8/1/2021       1
    8/2/2021       2
```

```
df_test = df_dates.apply(lambda x: df_values.loc[x])
```

Essentially, the `'7/1/2021'` date in the list of dates is throwing a key error in the `loc` function for `df_values`

Comment: The function itself should catch and handle the error, which precludes using a lambda expression as the argument to `df_dates.apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch and handle the error in the `lambda` function, as chepner suggests.
I suppose your data are in a dataframe like this:

```
df_values = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['8/1/2021', '8/2/2021'], 'values': [1, 2]}).set_index('dates')
```

```
          values
dates           
8/1/2021       1
8/2/2021       2
```

And you store the data to be processed in a `pandas.Series`:

```
df_dates = pd.Series(['7/1/2021', '8/1/2021', '8/2/2021'])
```

With these assumptions, a solution could be:

```
df_test = df_dates.apply(lambda x: df_values.loc[x].values[0] if x in df_values.index else 'no value')
```

So you will get the `pandas.Series`:

```
0    no value
1           1
2           2
dtype: object
```

Or, if you want the result in the form of a `list`:

```
df_test = df_dates.apply(lambda x: df_values.loc[x].values[0] if x in df_values.index else 'no value').to_list()
```

```
['no value', 1, 2]
```

You should tailor the `.loc` and `.apply` methods based on the way you stored your data and what do you want to get as result. The general structure of the `lambda` call to catch and handle an error is:

```
pandas.Series.apply(lambda input: output_1 if condition is True else output_2)
```

Comment: so I tried this example, but when I do this it doesn't return as a dataframe and is almost returning indicidual dataframes within a list whereas if I do df_dates.iloc[1:] it works.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hoping it may be more helpful :-)

Comment: figured it out! for some reason loc was returning the whole series.... we needed the line item()